# Wait for data with Indy10

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have a TCP "Server", that is sending data every 20 seconds. I am trying to receive this data and display the result. Currently, the data is displayed 3 times instead of once. It then waits another 20 seconds, and again displays the data 3 times.

```
with Client do
begin

    Connect;

    while True do
    begin
        try
        if IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then
        begin
            WriteLn('Bytes available: ' IntToStr(IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size));
            IOHandler.ReadBytes(buffer, IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size);
        end;
        except
            on e : exception do
                writeln(e.message);
        end;

        if(buffer <> nil) then
        begin
            SetString(msg, PAnsiChar(@buffer[0], length(buffer));
            buffer := nil;
            IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
        end;

        write(msg);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Right now it's running within a console application. Just wanted to write some simple test code, to try and read data from a socket connection.

Comment: It is inside the body of  program procedure. That pretty much is all of the code, aside from setting the host and port numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem I was having, by moving the write(msg) into the if statement checking if the buffer is not nil.

```
with Client do
begin

    Connect;

    while True do
    begin
        try
            if IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then
            begin
                WriteLn('Bytes available: ' IntToStr(IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size));
                IOHandler.ReadBytes(buffer, IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size);
            end;
        except
            on e : exception do
                writeln(e.message);
        end;

        if(buffer <> nil) then
        begin
            SetString(msg, PAnsiChar(@buffer[0], length(buffer));
            buffer := nil;
            IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
            write(msg); {only write out the message when the buffer is not nil}
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `write(msg)` on every loop iteration regardless of whether you actually read any new data or not.  You are resetting your `buffer` to nil after assigning it to `msg`, but you are not resetting `msg` to `''` after writing it.  So each loop iteration is writing whatever `msg` already holds until you assign a new value to it.

Try this code instead:

```
with Client do
begin
  Connect;
  buffer := nil;
  repeat
    try
      if IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then
      begin
        WriteLn('Bytes available: ' + IntToStr(IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size));
        IOHandler.ReadBytes(buffer, IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size);
        SetString(msg, PAnsiChar(buffer), Length(buffer));
        Write(msg);
        buffer := nil;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        WriteLn(E.Message);
    end;
  until not Connected;
end;
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
with Client do
begin
  Connect;
  buffer := nil;
  repeat
    try
      IOHandler.ReadBytes(buffer, -1);
      WriteLn('Bytes read: ' + Length(buffer));
      SetString(msg, PAnsiChar(buffer), Length(buffer));
      Write(msg);
      buffer := nil;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        WriteLn(E.Message);
    end;
  until not Connected;
end;
```

Or even:

```
with Client do
begin
  Connect;
  repeat
    try
      if IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(IdTimeoutDefault) then
      begin
        WriteLn('Bytes available: ' + IntToStr(IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size));
        Write(IOHandler.InputBufferAsString(en8bit));
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        WriteLn(E.Message);
    end;
  until not Connected;
end;
```

Comment: I had left the write statement in the loop, because I had just finished writing something similar in C, and I noticed that when the socket is blocked waiting to recv().